# Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath

Tags: android-viewbinding

Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No cached version of androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0 available for offline mode.
> Could not resolve com.android.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No cached version of com.android.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.android.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0 available for offline mode.

I invalidated caches and restarted android studio and also my laptop and also added this dependency:
implementation 'com.android.databinding:viewbinding:8.2.0'
but didnot worked